# Error shown while taking backup installation on loaclhost in prestashop

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

Error shown while taking backup installation on loaclhost in prestashop.... Please help in resolving this error. 
show this message:-
Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'aranyc68_aranyas'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 0):

First check whether you have db permissions for the user: 'aranyc68_aranyas',
if you have permission check  the following :
Go to config folder of your prestashop project and open settings.inc.php and check the following

```
 define('_DB_SERVER_', 'yourdbserver');
 define('_DB_NAME_', 'yourdbname');
 define('_DB_USER_', 'yourdbuser');
 define('_DB_PASSWD_', 'yourdbuserpwd');
```